# Powershell Get-Random with Constraints

Tags: powershell

I'm currently using the `Get-Random` function of Powershell to randomly pull a set number of rows from a csv. I need to create a constraint that says if one id is pulled, find the other ids that match it and pull their value.

Here is what I currently have:

```
$chosenOnes = Import-CSV C:\Temp\pk2.csv | sort{Get-Random} | Select -first 6

$i = 1

$count = $chosenOnes | Group-Object householdID


foreach ($row in $count)
{

    if ($row.count -gt 1)
    {

        $students = $row.Group.Student

        foreach ($student in $students)
        {

            $name = $student.tostring()

            #...do something

            $i = $i + 1
         }
    }
    else
    {

        $name = $row.Group.Student

        if($i -le 5)
        {
            #...do something
        }
        else
        {
            #...do something
        }
        $i = $i + 1
    }
}
```

Example dataset

```
ID,name
165,Ernest Hemingway
1204,Mark Twain
1578,Stephen King
1634,Charles Dickens
1726,George Orwell
7751,John Doe
7751,Tim Doe
```

In this example, there are 7 rows but I'm randomly selecting 6 in my code. What needs to happen is when `ID=7751` then I must return both rows where `ID=7751`. The IDs cannot not be statically set in the code.

Comment: I am not really sure where random comes into this...like sort random?

Comment: @ArcSet The `sort{Get-Random}` was something that I found. I'm open to different ways of randomly selecting from a csv but I need to be able to get like IDs if one is randomly chosen. Does that make sense? Maybe `Get-Random` isn't the way to go...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Get-Random` directly, with `-Count`, to extract a given number of random elements from a collection.

```
$allRows = Import-CSV C:\Temp\pk2.csv

$chosenHouseholdIDs = ($allRows | Get-Random -Count 6).householdID
```

Then filter all rows by whether their `householdID` column contains one of the 6 randomly selected rows' `householdID` values (PSv3+ syntax), using the `-in` array-containment operator:

```
$allRows | Where-Object householdID -in $chosenHouseholdIDs
```

---

#### Optional reading: performance considerations:

`$allRows | Get-Random -Count 6` is not only conceptually simpler, but also much faster than `$allRows | Sort-Object { Get-Random } | Select-Object -First 6`

Using the [`Time-Command` function](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/9e1f13978620b09ab2d15da5535d1b27) to compare the performance of two approaches, using a 1000-row test file with 10 columns yields the following sample timings on my Windows 10 VM in Windows PowerShell - note that the `Sort-Object { Get-Random }`-based solution is more than 15(!) times slower:

```
Factor Secs (100-run avg.) Command                                                        TimeSpan
------ ------------------- -------                                                        --------
1.00   0.007               $allRows | Get-Random -Count 6                                 00:00:00.0072520
15.65  0.113               $allRows | Sort-Object { Get-Random } | Select-Object -First 6 00:00:00.1134909
```

Similarly, a single pass through all rows to find matching IDs via array-containment operator `-in` performs much better than looping over the randomly selected IDs and searching all rows for each.

Comment: Technically, both of these answers solve my problem. Choose the one you’re most comfortable with.

Comment: I see the benefit. I'd like to take this a step further: right now if I get 6 random IDs out of 7 and the last ID chosen has a matching ID, I end up with a total of 7 results. How can this be modified to end up with 6 results even if the last one chosen has a match but I still have to return the match. Does that make sense?

Comment: @BobbyZimmerman: I'm not sure I fully understand, but you can pipe to `Get-Random -Count 6` _again_; if this is not what you meant, please create a _new_ question and provide more detail; feel free to ping me here once you have done so.

Comment: I've posted a new question that relates to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58738416/powershell-get-random-group-by-id

Answer (score 1):

I tried sticking with your beginning and came up with this.

```
$Array = Import-CSV C:\test\StudtentTest.csv
$Array | Sort{Get-Random} | select -first 2 | %{
    $id = $_.id
    $Array | ?{$_.id -eq $id} | %{
        $_
    }
}
```

`$Array` will be your parsed CSV

We pipe in and sort by random select -first 2 (in this case)
Save the ID of the object into $id and then search the array for that ID and dispaly each that matches

If same ID does match you end up with something like

```
ID   name           
--   ----           
7751 John Doe       
7751 Tim Doe        
1634 Charles Dickens
```